# Login and Scrape without Selenium

Tags: selenium, authentication, scrape, python-requests-html

I am trying to monitor various investments I hold through a single database (mysql with an MS Access Frontend). I have sourced solution for most of them as can source the unit price / share price without needing to login to a portal. My issue is for one of my investments I can only find out the value by logging in.

I have got this working through my laptop using Selenium but have my raspberry pi doing all the harvesting and Selenium is flakey on it and keeps breaking when I do updates etc.

I am hoping someone may be able to direct me on what python module to use for performing the same without selenium. For my other harvesting I am using a mix of requests_html & urllib.request so slightly have them as a preference but couldn't work it out. Have also attempted mechanize but no luck.

I have created a test account on the website and have those details in the code however it doesn't allow access to what is behind the login but my issue is being able to submit the login details in the first place.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Edge(r"C:\Python\edgedriver\msedgedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://app.raizinvest.com.au/login')

time.sleep(4)  
browser.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("testaccountraiz@yahoo.com")
browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("Test4321")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[4]/button").click()
time.sleep(3)
print(str(browser.find_elements_by_class_name("page-content__banner-account-value")[0].text))
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selenium code keeps on breaking cause you are using xpath like this

`/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[4]/button` -

you can even introduce `explicit waits` in your code to have more **reliability**.

Helium is one such tool which is bit advance than selenium but have it's own limitation such as will work only in chrome and FF and with Python itself.

If you are interest in Selenium Python bindings, I would re-write your code as below  :

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://app.raizinvest.com.au/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys('testaccountraiz@yahoo.com')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys('Test4321')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[Selenium - Python - Explicit waits](http://from%20selenium.webdriver.support.ui%20import%20WebDriverWait%20from%20selenium.webdriver.common.by%20import%20By%20from%20selenium.webdriver.support%20import%20expected_conditions%20as%20EC)

[Python - Helium - Installation](https://selenium-python-helium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

[Python - Helium - API's](https://selenium-python-helium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but I am wanting to use something other than Selenium as it doesn't work reliably on my raspberry pi. Also had a look at Helium on your advice but it needs 64bit os it seems and I have the 32bit version installed.

Comment: Well it's hardware limitation you have. Since you wanna automate browser I would personally recommend you to use selenium. Did you try with explicit waits ? Is it still not stable with explicit wait ? Other one more option you have is cypress.

Comment: No I have issues with selenium and chrome versions being incompatible and when I do certain upgrades etc. it often breaks and I have to download depreciated versions of one or the other. I have Selenium working just at the moment but it has failed about 3 times in the past few months and takes me ages to work it out each time. I would rather  a headless non browser type option like requests_html if it can work also because it is lighter on hardware and more stable.

Comment: Yes headless is also one good option, or there is a way where you can auto upgrade chrome driver, you don't have to manually set it up

Comment: that is what causes the issue I think. When I run the auto updates of all packages etc. is what stuffs it up. Part of the issue appears to be that yes it uses the chrome driver but "chrome" itself is not available for raspberry pi and instead it is "chromium" which is part of the issue. Anyhow that is why I am really trying to avoid selenium. All my stock portfolio pulls in automatically and I need this to do it reliably as well. This Pi is also running my Home Assistant server and other home based servers also so although I should start over from scratch isn't an option atm